# WCF REST parameter object is null

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, api, rest

I have created WCF REST API. I have implemented following service interface and service method for the API.

service interface:

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
ObjAPI GetAPIRequest(ObjAPI objAPI)
```

service :

```
public ObjAPI GetAPIRequest(ObjAPI objAPI)
{
   return new ExternalAPI().GetAPIRequest(objAPI);

}
```

code of ObjAPI class

```
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Namespace = "")]
    public class ObjAPI
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]        
        public int ID { get; set; }   

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
        public Client Client { get; set; }       


    }
}
```

My ObjAPI contain another object “Client”, then I Have passed Following Xml to the service.

```
<ObjAPI> 
<ID> 1 </ID>
<Client> 
< ClientNumber>0067HA000001</ ClientNumber>
</Client > 
</ ObjAPI >
```

But in the “ GetAPIRequest” method, ID field is getting its value and client object become null.

How can I fix this Issue?

Thank you ….

Comment: Can you please share ObjAPI class?

Comment: [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Namespace = "")]          
    public class ObjAPI
    {
        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]        
        public int ID { get; set; }   

        [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
        public Client Client { get; set; }       


    }
}

Comment: @Prasad - 1. Edit your question and add your code there, please.  2.  Post the code for `GetAPIRequest`, as the issue may be there.

Comment: @Tim : actually at the service class object value getting null vale.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IInterface
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
    ObjAPI GetAPIRequest(ObjAPI objAPI)
}

public class Service: IInterface
{
    public ObjAPI GetAPIRequest(ObjAPI objAPI)
    {
       return new ExternalAPI().GetAPIRequest(objAPI);
    }
}

[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class ObjAPI
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]        
    public int ID { get; set; }   

    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]
    public Client Client { get; set; }       
}
```

We also must set DataContract and DataMember attributes for Client class

```
[System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract(Namespace = "")]
public class Client
{
    [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataMember]        
    public string ClientNumber { get; set; }     
}
```